# Different log files for Grails applications deployed within one servlet container

Tags: grails, deployment, groovy, log4j, config

I have 2 grails applications packed with --nojars parameter in grails war command. All grails framework libraries are moved to server and they are loader in shared.loader line in tomcat servlet container.

My question is, how can I set different loggers for this different application. 
Now log4j = {..} produce the static variable which is shared  between two applications.
I'd like to have different logs for each one. 
When deploying the war files produced by grails build command without --nojars everithing went well, and each application had its own log file.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hm, do you mean that both applications have exact same, one, shared class loader?

Comment: Actually, there is just one application who loading grails framework libraries - tomcat(by shared.loader section in catalina.properties)/

Comment: Why not to put it into different applications? I mean not using shared.loaded. Or it's a Halloween project? :)

Comment: sorry, but I don't know what do you mean with "Halloween project".
I described, that I don't pack all grails applications with all grails libraries, because on my application server right now are deployed 3 application, and each is 500-700 Kb. If I pack them with grails libraries they become to 20Mb.
There are different reasons, why I do this - deploy is faster, less memory to use.

Comment: :) Halloween project is a project made to scary developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there should be two different web applications as well.  If you do not want the duplicate libraries packaged again, just give them a 'provided' scope and make sure they are available in your instance of Tomcat.

Comment: Sorry, just realised that this question is quite old ... oh well.